# Clojure map key with spaces in the key name

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I am pretty new to Clojure. I have a map of results from a database and it contains key values such as:

```
{:Unique Product ID "09876" :ProductName "XYZ"}
```

I want to retrieve the values from the map but I am having problems getting the Unique Product ID.

```
ProductID (str ( map-name ":Unique Product ID"))
```

Product Name works fine using:

```
ProductName (str ( map-name :ProductName"))
```

I'm not sure how to handle the space in the Product ID field key. How should I retrieve the value for that key from the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try (keyword "Unique Product ID")

Answer (score 11):

Space is *not* a valid character in a keyword, you are trying to do something that will almost certainly cause pain in the future.

Note that the keyword function does not validate it's input, so @jeff-johnston is incorrect I'm afraid.

Lengthy discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure/WvXYkvLoQhI/discussion

clojuredocs was updated with new docstrings following that discussion see here:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/keyword

Comment: oh, that's good to know.  http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-17 suggests that some time in the future "arbitrary symbol support" *might* be implemented, but i can't find a relevant ticket.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(keyword)` as Jeff indicates, but I think you would be better off in general if you transformed the map you get back from the database query into one whose keys have no spaces.  I find this function useful for the purpose:

```
(defn despace [m] 
  (zipmap (map #(keyword (clojure.string/replace (name %) " " "_")) (keys m))
          (vals m)))
```

Then use underscores in place of the spaces:

```
(:Unique_Product_ID (despace {(keyword "Unique Product ID") "09876" :ProductName "XYZ"}))
#=> "09876"
```